# Basic Shippable .yml file for Laravel 5.1 projects

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, yaml

I've been struggling the past 2 hours to find a basic `.yml` files to setup my Laravel project with **Shippable** and surprisingly I can't find any, can I get a basic one so that I can understand how `.yml` works?

Comment: http://docs.shippable.com/yml_reference/

Answer (score 2):

Follow this tutorial - 
http://viveksoni.net/shippable-continues-integration-php-laravel-5-2/

To setup shippable.yml for laravel use following yml-

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.6

services:
  - mysql

addons:
  hosts:
    - example.org

before_script:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - composer self-update -n
  - composer install  #downloads vendor
  - composer install --prefer-dist -n  # no idea
  - mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON *.* TO shippable@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ''; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"  #creating shippable user
  - mysql -e "create database if not exists sample;" # create database
  - mysql -e "show databases;" # lists databases
  - cp .env.testing .env # creates .env file
  - php artisan key:generate # generates secure key
  - php artisan config:cache  # caches config (without it laravel throws error that secure key is not there)
  - php artisan migrate --env=testing #creates database table
  - php artisan db:seed # seeds database with seeders
script:
  - phpunit --log-junit shippable/testresults/junit.xml --coverage-xml shippable/codecoverage
```

This would be enough for getting phpunit testcases running.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13006691)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩  Done :)

Answer (score 0):

After searching all over the internet and dev forums I could not find shippable.yml file for my laravel project.

so I have created following file which is working fine.

```
language: php


php:
  - 5.6

services:
  - mysql

addons:
  hosts:
    - example.org

before_script:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install nginx
  - sudo cp ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf.default ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/php-fpm.conf
  - ~/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/sbin/php-fpm
  - sudo cp -f shippable-conf/site-nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site-nginx.conf
  - sudo sed -e "s?%BUILD_DIR%?$(pwd)?g" --in-place /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site-nginx.conf
  - sudo service nginx start
  - sudo php shippable-conf/composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin --filename=composer
  - sudo mv shippable-conf/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
  - composer install

script:
  - phpunit  --log-junit shippable/testresults/junit.xml --coverage-xml shippable/codecoverage tests/ExampleTest.php

after_script:
  - sudo service nginx stop
```

for that first I downloaded shippable.yml for nginx from [here](https://github.com/shippableSamples/sample_php_nginx) since my server is nginx but you can download from various different options available for PHP from [here](https://github.com/shippableSamples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=php)

After that I changed php version from 5.4 to 5.6 in original file for laravel requirement.

Then I created a folder in my project named **shippable-conf** and put site-nginx.conf(nginx config file) and [composer-setup.php](https://getcomposer.org/installer) file into it(just to maintain the folder structure) and updated site-nginx.conf path in origin shippable.yml(line no. 19).

In the end just added composer installation commands in original shippable.yml file just below nginx start command, pushed on git and it worked for me.